# Kurento multiple one-to-many broadcast sessions

Tags: kurento

I want to create more than one broadcasting sessions, (like chat rooms so there could be n number of masters each broadcasting to different group of viewers).

Is multiple broadcasting sessions possible? if so how can I achieve this? can I do something like the implementation of one-to-one calls given in the tutorials on github?

Currently my code is same as the `kurento-one2many-call` Node.js example provided on [Github](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/release-5.1/kurento-one2many-call).

EDIT:
I have been going through the code and tutorials and realized that this might be achievable by introducing different pipelines for each 'chat room'. Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do this would be to create one pipeline for each broadcast session. This is similar to what the [kurento-room](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-room) framework and [kurento-group-call](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/develop/kurento-group-call) tutorial do. Basically, you create one pipeline every time a new room (broadcast session in your case) is created, and start creating endpoint inside the session's pipeline. That way, once the session is finished, you can destroy the pipeline without interfering with other active sessions.

If you are planning on supporting 200+ users per broadcast, I'd suggest you match 1 pipeline per KMS, and spawn new KMS-VM instances as needed. That way, you can create an elastic cloud based on Kurento.

Comment: thanks for this help, can you please suggest how to acheive that, by some code example or any help setting up for multiple.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan Check any of those projects

Comment: Wouldn't you do that by setting up multiple websocket servers?

Comment: hello @igracia, my question is different but I think you can help me.

I am developing multiparty conferencing in nodejs using Kurento (kurento-utils-js on client side and kurento-client package on server side)

When someone speaks (either local or on remote stream), I want to show the audio level on user interface (UI) to just show that he/she is speaking. Please help me do achieve this.