# Handle Multiple stream in Kurento

Tags: kurento, fiware-kurento

I want to integrate multiple camera with Kurento and play their live feed at same html page and at same time. Is it possible to have this with single Kurento. If yes, then please guide me how to proceed.

Currently I am able to take a single camera stream and play its live feed on html page by implementing Kurento-tutorial node. Please guide to add more camera feed on that page.

I also need to know that is there any limitation on the number of cameras that we can attach or number of live feed we can show in single page with single kurento instance. Are there any existing performance analysis results?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I don't know about limitation on number of cameras. But for now I am able to view streams from four cameras on single screen.

Comment: At what resolution and bitrate?

Comment: I would start by looking at this question [Kurento multiple one-to-many broadcast sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965288/kurento-multiple-one-to-many-broadcast-sessions?rq=4). Take note that you will need to make multiple pipelines.